# Should utility classes in Java EE application be EJB's or classes with static methods

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-ee, ejb

I am making a Java EE 7 application. I need to have some utility classes so I don't write the same code n times.

Is it good practice to make them EJB's and inject where necessary or is it better to make them ordinary classes with static methods.

How would this affect performance? My understanding is that making them EJB improves performance as with ordinary classes with static methods, only one bean could access one utility method at a time. On the other hand, making them EJB's would require the Application Server to instantiate a pool of those utility EJB's which seems to improve performance, buy maybe can cause more memory usage.

On the other hand my utility classes would be simple, mostly one liners, and wouldn't have any complex processing, nor they keep track or depend on the state of the object.

The examples of my utility classes are the following:

- check if the string doesn't contain digits or special characters
- check if an email address is correct
- create the new Response object with the default values (statusCode, message) (this Response object is used for Web Services as a return type)
- etc

Answer (score 3):

> My understanding is that making them EJB improves performance as with ordinary classes with static methods, only one bean could access one utility method at a time.

No way. Consider `Math` as a typical utility class. Any number of threads can call `Math.sqrt` at the same time and there's no added overhead.

You can't beat the performance of a static method for such tasks. The only reason for using something else is flexibility. Imagine, there was a slightly imprecise but much faster `sqrt` computing method in `Math2`. There's no way how you could swap to the faster implementation without modifying your code. With EJBs, it'd be trivial.

> making them EJB's would require the Application Server to instantiate a pool of those utility EJB's

I doubt that "pool" is the right word here, as a utility class corresponds with a stateless bean and then a single instance is sufficient.

Invoking a bean can't be faster than a static method call, it may be slower, but not much. It's not the performance what should guide your decision.

For all three examples of yours I'd go for a static method. It's improbably that you'll ever need a different implementation or even switch between multiple implementations at runtime. It might happen, but then you can easily adapt.